# Plotting components of three-dimensional array in d3

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I'm trying to figure out if I can work with my current data structure to create a scatterplot in d3. What I have is a three-dimensional array, `thetas`, with dimensions *i*, *j*, and *k*. Dimension *j* expands with user input. Dimensions *i* and *k* are fixed at *i*=2 and *k*=3. For a given *i*, I want to plot the first two entries of *k* as the *x* and *y* values for a scatterplot for all *j*. I can't figure out how to do this. Currently, to plot *i* = 1, I have

```
    xx = d3.scale.linear()
    .domain([0,1])
    .range([margins.yylMarginFactor * width, (1 - margins.yyrMarginFactor) * width]);
    yy = d3.scale.linear()
    .domain([0,1])
    .range([(1 - margins.xxbMarginFactor) * height, margins.xxtMarginFactor * height]);
    var tmp = chart.selectAll(".vis3points").data(thetas[0][0], function (d, i) { return i; } );
    tmp
        .enter().insert("svg:circle")
        .attr("class", "vis3points")
        .attr("cx", function (d, i) { return xx(d); })
        .attr("cy", yy(d))
        .attr("r", 3);
    tmp.transition()
        .duration(10)
        .attr("cx", function (d, i) { return xx(d); })
        .attr("cy", yy(d))
    tmp.exit()
        .transition().duration(10).attr("r",0).remove();
```

Is this the right direction? What structure should I be using?

Comment: Is it possible to paste your code on jsFiddle or similar place? It's not so clear with your requirement.

Comment: It will take me a while to put this together, but I'll try.